# Spring TaskScheduler Bean not injected

Tags: java, spring, task, jobs, schedule

I need to schedule a job when the a session is created.
So I created my HttpSessionListener :

```
@Component
public class WebSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

//@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "taskScheduler")
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;
@Autowired
private PanierService panierService;

//Notification that a session was created.
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionCreatedEvent) {

    Runnable viderPanier20mnJob = PanierJobs.getViderPanier20mnJob(httpSessionCreatedEvent.getSession());
    taskScheduler.schedule(viderPanier20mnJob, PanierJobs.getNextDateTime());
    System.out.println("Session Created Called! -----------------------");
}
```

**But my big problem here is that my TaskScheduler bean is not injected (NoSuchBeanDefinition or sometimes it just pops a NullPointerException).**

Here is my TaskScheduler (taken from an example where it was working) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class JobSchedulingConfig{

  @Bean
   public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot, I don't have a configuration file. It is Java based configuration (as seen on the second code snippet).
@Autowired and @Qualifier don't work for TaskScheduler (works for PanierService)

Comment: Is `@Autowired` not working for `taskScheduler`? Is it auto-scanned? share spring config file.

Comment: Could you please try with only `@Autowired`. Remove `@Qualifier`.

Comment: could you please share the xml configuration you're using? have you defined taskScheduler in your configuration?

Comment: I don't have an XML configuration file, I'm using Spring Boot.
Here is an example that is similar : https://github.com/joshlong/boot-examples/blob/master/websockets/src/main/java/demo/Application.java

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this with a simple Spring MVC web server.  I was unable to find either a taskScheduler bean or the ScheduledTaskRegistrar bean in the context.

To solve this, I changed my configuration class to implement SchedulingConfigurer, and within the configureTasks method, I set the task scheduler to one which is explicitly declared in the configuration (as a bean.)  Here's my java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class BeansConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(); //single threaded by default
    }
}
```

This has the unfortunate side effect of me declaring the task scheduler, instead of letting Spring default it as it sees fit.  I chose to use the same (single threaded executor within a concurrent task scheduler) implementation as Spring 4.2.4 is using.

By implementing the SchedulingConfigurer interface, I've ensured that the task scheduler I created is the same one that Spring's scheduling code uses.

Comment: I was already implementing the *SchedulingConfigurer* interface and I had the very same problem. For some reason the *configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar)* method is called only after the TaskScheduler instance is retrieved (via taskScheduler() method) and injected in my component. @allenru thanks for the snippet!